# Is 更新予約 a valid term for a "Scheduled Update"?

Tags: pragmatics

My Samsung tablet has a setting item ソフトウェアの更新予約. Switching language to English has it "Scheduled software updates". I searched for 更新予約 on internet and did not find many hits for this term. Has Samsung got it right by labeling "Scheduled software updates" as ソフトウェアの更新予約?

Comment: それで合ってるだろうね。更新の予約＝scheduled software updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

予約 is usually for a one-time event (e.g., レストランの予約). If this "scheduled update" refers to a one-time event (like upgrading from Windows 7 to 10), 更新(の)予約 is totally fine.

If this "scheduled update" refers to periodic events (like weekly software patches scheduled at midnight), 予約 sounds a bit off to me. ソフトウェアの更新スケジュール or ソフトウェアの定期的(な)更新 would be better as a menu item.